# Is it better to use txt file to get the current counter value instead of database?

Tags: laravel

I am working on a website in laravel, wherein I am loading a current counter value from the database. And then the user clicks on the button to increase the score.

But as the website has around 4000 concurrent users at any given time, the Database connection is taking its toll on the server and resulting in timeouts.

If I load the current score from the txt file and then write it back to the same file, will it be better?

Or should I use an Application variable to store the score?

I have tried using the cache, but it doesn't pull the latest value. Database optimization is also not working due to the number of users.

I am looking at best way to show and increment counter without database usage.

Comment: Have you considered using redis as a counter?

Comment: Trying it out. Will update here if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A database would do a better job. A NoSQL database is perfect for your use case. You can use Redis, it stores the data in-memory (RAM), which means read and write operations will be much faster than other database that operates in secondary disk (Hard Drive).

Redis itself supports data structure to increment values, using `INCR` command. `INCR` increments the number stored at key by one. If the key does not exist, it is set to 0 before performing the operation.

For example your key that holds the value is `my_counter`. You can play around with `redis-cli` like so.

```
redis>  SET my_counter "10"

"OK"

redis>  INCR my_counter

(integer) 11

redis>  GET my_counter

"11"
```

Fortunately, there is a Redis client for Laravel. You can have a read here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redis

Good luck :)

Edit 1:

If a high amount of user is causing the server to slow down, you have other server and architectural options that can be set alongside a new database. Such as horizontal and vertical scaling.

---

References:

https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis